# What happens when we use usestate without any parameters (in React hooks)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

what will happen if usestate does not initialised with any value?

Eg:  const [growth, setGrowth] = useState();

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The implicit value is then (as it is for any elided function parameter) `undefined`.